# Vim: How do I override a command with a new command that uses the old command?

Tags: vim

My Ruby folding expression is causing auto-completion (`<C-n>`/`<C-p>`) to slow down dramatically, which is a massive pain. When I switch to manual folding, auto-completion becomes instant.

To work around that I'd like the folding to be "on demand", i.e. it only calculates folds when i do `zx` or `zX`. The plan:

1. Set Ruby code default folding method to `manual`
2. When opening a Ruby file, locally map `zx` to switch folding method to `expr` and run `zx`, then switch folding method back to `manual`
3. Repeat #2 for `zX`

The issue is, when I've overridden `zx`, how do I call the "old" `zx`?

---

Perfect answer by Kent, here's my final working solution (`ftplugin/ruby.vim`):

```
if &filetype == 'ruby'
    setlocal foldmethod=manual
    nn <buffer> <silent> zx :set foldmethod=expr<CR>:norm! zx<CR>:set foldmethod=manual<CR>
    nn <buffer> <silent> zX :set foldmethod=expr<CR>:norm! zX<CR>:set foldmethod=manual<CR>
end
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood you right... but you can call `:norm! zx` to bypass your mapping.

Comment: One way that comes to my mind is using `:norm!  zx`. But I will wait because others might have more interesting solutions. Anyway, consider that if you go this route, you can use an auto command to create that map locally when you enter your ruby buffers, so others will use the "original" `zx`. Also, are you scanning for included files? That generally causes some slowness too

Comment: Sorry @Kent I think I wrote at the same time

Comment: @Kent Perfect! I was hoping the answer would be that simple :) Make it an answer and claim your rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `:normal` command, you can execute NORMAL mode command. And if you added a `!`, you will bypass mappings. For the example from yours,

```
:norm! zx
```

may help.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `:noremap` series of commands, rather than plain `:map`, you prevent any mappings from firing recursively. So you can safely call the "old" zx inside your mapping just by using zx directly. Example for your case:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> zx :set foldmethod=expr<CR>zx:set foldmethod=manual<CR>
```

Comment: So that's what the "nore" part of mapping mean, nice